EF Core 9, inserting into a MySQL table with Composite Unique Constraint Best practice?
I'm working with a MySQL table that has a composite unique constraint on two columns (column1 and column2), like this:
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    column1 INT,
    column2 INT,
    column3 VARCHAR(100),
    UNIQUE KEY unique_column1_column2 (column1, column2)
);

I need to insert a large number of rows into this table while skipping any rows that would cause unique constraint violations due to the composite unique key.
So far i have narrowed down my options:
A: Rely on DB to enforce the constraint. This would however force me to insert each entry individually in order to skip on duplicate-entry exceptions, thus increasing the amount of trips to the DB.
B: Check if an entry already exists and only insert if not exists. This would cause same problem as A, increasing DB trips.
C: Try/catch save all the changes on the context, persisting all rows in 1 query. In the catch, i can then try and insert each row individually and skip duplicates. This just seems stupid.
So i guess my question is:
What is the best way to efficiently insert a number of rows into a MySQL table using EF Core 9, with a composite unique constraint while skipping duplicates?

I need to insert a large number of rows into this table while skipping any rows that would cause unique constraint violations due to the composite unique key, how many rows ? Is this a one-time job or a day-to-day  task ? You could use INSERT IGNORE to discard duplicates , use a single insert statement for all the values

If this is a many-to-many mapping table, see the tips: Many-to-many

Voted to reopen: the duplicate is a SQL solution, not EF.

@GertArnold IMO there are two possibilities to avoid dupes in MySQL 1. INSERT IGNORE if you want to skip duplicates and other related fields and INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for the duplicates which some fields have changed and you want to preserve the latest. Depneds on the use case. And the best solution would be to let the dbms handle this.

@ErgestBasha The question is "What is the best way (...) using EF Core 9". EF won't generate this specific syntax, so the question is valid. Although it's also likely to be a duplicate, because this is a common problem. But then the question be better closed as duplicate of an EF-question along these lines.
